# Empty string in viewmodel gives string "&nbsp;" in selected record of gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, syncfusion

When a string is empty in a VM-properrty it is shown correctly in the gridview itself.
However, when I want to get the data from the selected record, the content is the string `&nbsp;`.

Whether the column is visible or not does not change the behaviour.
Is there something special I need to include to work with empty strings?

**Gridview:**

```
@{
    Html.Syncfusion()
        .Grid<InternalCompany>("internalCompaniesGrid")
        .ActionMode(ActionMode.Server)
        .EnableEnsureSelection()
        .Datasource(Model.InternalCompanies)
        .SelectionMode(SelectionMode.Single)
        .RowsSelectionMode(RowsSelectionMode.Normal)
        .AutoFormat(Skins.Office2007Silver)
        .AllowKeyboardNavigation(true)
        .AllowSelection(true)
        .EnableHighlighting(true)
        .ClientSideEvents(events => events.OnLoad("onLoadGrid"))
        .ClientSideEvents(events => events.OnRecordSelectionEvent("clientSideOnInternalCompanyRecordSelected"))
        .Column(column =>
            {
                column.Add(c => c.Base64Timestamp).Visible(false);
                column.Add(c => c.ID).Width(40);
                column.Add(c => c.Name).HeaderText("Naam").Width(270).TextAlign(TextAlignment.Left);
                column.Add(c => c.Street).Visible(false);
                column.Add(c => c.HouseNumber).Visible(false);
                column.Add(c => c.Bus);
                column.Add(c => c.Zip).Visible(false);
                column.Add(c => c.City).Visible(false);
            })
        .Editing(edit =>
            {
                edit.AllowEdit(false);
                edit.AllowNew(false);
                edit.AllowDelete(false);
                edit.EditMode(GridEditMode.Normal);
                edit.SaveOnEnter(true);
                edit.PrimaryKey(key => key.Add(p => p.ID));
            })
        .ToolBar(tools => tools.Add(GridToolBarItems.Custom))
        .Width(660)
        .Render();
}
```

**Relevant jquery code:**

```
function clientSideOnInternalCompanyRecordSelected(sender, args) {
    $('#Bus').attr("value", getValue("Bus", null, args, function () { return args.record.Bus; }));
}
```

The piece of code  `return args.record.Bus;` gives the string `&nbsp;`.

Also when using the developer tools to inspect the value of `record`, it indicates that the empty string is changed to `&nbsp;`.
Happens in both Chrome as IE.

**UPDATE**

After some extra investigation, we found out that an empty string or 1 single space gives the above problem. When the property content is 2 spaces, the content of `args.record.Bus` is also 2 spaces.
But still no clue why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported issue `Empty string column returns &nbsp as value` is defect, and in order for you to get a solution for this behavior, please contact **Syncfusion** Support or you may also open a support ticket by logging in to direct trac account and mentioning this forum link for reference

https://www.syncfusion.com/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=/support/directtrac